# Java FX sample is throwing error while opening it in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2

I am exactly following the steps mentioned in the following doc under the following heading:

[How Do I Run a Sample in an IDE?](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm)

However, in Netbeans 7.4, I am getting the following error:

```
   ant -f C:\\Users\\akhare\\Desktop\\javafx_samples-2_2_51-windows\\javafx-samples-2.2.51\\src\\Ensemble jfxsa-run
C:\Users\akhare\Desktop\javafx_samples-2_2_51-windows\javafx-samples-2.2.51\src\Ensemble\nbproject\build-impl.xml:88: The J2SE Platform is not correctly set up.
 Your active platform is: default_platform, but the corresponding property "platforms.default_platform.home" is not found in the project's properties files. 
 Either open the project in the IDE and setup the Platform with the same name or add it manually.
 For example like this:
     ant -Duser.properties.file=<path_to_property_file> jar (where you put the property "platforms.default_platform.home" in a .properties file)
  or ant -Dplatforms.default_platform.home=<path_to_JDK_home> jar (where no properties file is used)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Not sure why I am getting the aforementioned error. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to solution [here](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/cannot-compile-shoddybattleclient2.59844/), Which solved my problem, You need to go to your project properties and change your `java platform` from `JDK xxx(default)` to `JDK xxx`

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I try opening a project with those kind of errors, it asks me to resolve the problem.

What you can do now is right click on the project in the project window and choose properties.  In the Libraries node you can set the java platform.  Then it will build the project using that platform.

[image]

You can also use Manage platforms if you have another jdk to use.  If you're having trouble you have to say which jdk you're using.

Comment: In the Libraries Node , under Compile Tab, I see two jar files namely `lib/lucene-core-3.2.0.jar and lib/lucene-grouping-3.2.0.jar` and `javafx.classpath.extension` . What would you like me to do here? Could you please elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yashar's solution worked for me if you do a clean and build after.
To elaborate, right-click on project, select properties, click on libraries, click on manage platforms..., then add platform..., then just reselect your default platform, so it doesnt have the JDK x.x (Default), instead is just JDK x.x

the output window will look something like this:

```
Deleting: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\propertiesextractordemo\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\propertiesextractordemo\build\built-jar.properties
compile:
Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.3
jfx-deployment:
jar:
Copying 12 files to C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\propertiesextractordemo\dist\run411357528
jfx-project-run:
Executing C:\Users\xxx\Documents\NetBeansProjects\propertiesextractordemo\dist\run411357528\PropertiesExtractorDemo.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on

> Project libraries --> properties --> select a platform

even if a platform is selected, reselect it.